# Point External Domain and Sub Directories to Site's Folder

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

A lot of pages in our site uses an old subdomain for images, css and javascript files. I inherited the project from newbie developers and they didn't use any common design template. The result are hundreds of pages with static references to contents an examples are:

```
http://static.foo.bar/css/sample.css
http://static.foo.bar/brochure/css/sample.css
http://static.foo.bar/company/newsletter/js/common.js
http://static.foo.bar/images/version2/header.jpg
```

...and hundreds of other locations. I need to point them all to the main domain instead of the subdomain without creating rules for each of these on the .htaccess file. So:

```
http://static.foo.bar/css/sample.css 
should point to: 
http://www.foo.bar/css/sample.css

http://static.foo.bar/brochure/css/sample.css
should point to: 
http://www.foo.bar/brochure/css/sample.css

http://static.foo.bar/company/newsletter/js/common.js
should point to: 
http://www.foo.bar/company/newsletter/js/common.js

http://static.foo.bar/images/version2/header.jpg
should point to: 
http://www.foo.bar/images/version2/header.jpg
```

I know this is possible only I'm not a server guy. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Create an `.htaccess` file in the document root with this content:</s>

Add this to your server configuration, `%{HTTP_HOST}` check does not work from `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# bad matching: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^static\.foo\.bar [NC]
#
# correction, matching everything other than www.foo.bar :
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.foo\.bar$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.foo.bar/$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html#url

UPDATE:
Giving it a second though, if it's hosted on the same server, just add

```
ServerAlias static.foo.bar
```

to the www.foo.bar configuration to serve up the static content, too.

UPDATE #2 based on feedback:

This should work (works on my pc) in the .htaccess file, this redirects all requests coming to `static.foo.bar/*` to `www.foo.bar/*` :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^static\.foo\.bar [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://www.foo.bar/$1 [R,L]
```

And no, the ServerAlias command only works from a VirtualHost configuration:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. Will this work for the subdomain's root and its sub-directories?

Comment: This will redirect requests from one host name to another, with the same whole path, regardless of what the path is, exactly how you wrote in the question.

Comment: Not working though. I tried replacing http://www.foo.bar/nonexistent/$1 [L,R] as a test which should result in error 404 but all css and images are still fetching from subdomain successfully.

Comment: Hi Tamas. Actually it's  the other way around. I don't want the old subdomain to cater the static files. I want to host all our contents from our main domain. Also, I don't have access to http.conf which means I am pretty much limited to .htaccess as an option for the time being.

Comment: Do the two instances share the document root? Do you have access to the document root of the old instance?

Comment: Yes, they do share the same root folder, only different domain names

Comment: BTW, about the ServerAlias thingy, can this be done on htaccess?